# Saving Map Markers

Tags: android, sqlite, google-maps

I have a task to make a map app that puts markers on long click and display marker info on marker click. I also have to save it into SQLite. The problem is i am stuck and seems something is wrong. SQLite appeared empty after leaving app. I have no other idea how to save them. ANY help will be welcome.
The targer is on app exit the markers to be saved in DB and when launched again to be reloaded and displayed on the map. 
Here is my code so far:
MainActivity:

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
private JSONObject httpResponse;
private String markerCountry;
private String markerStreetAddress;
private JSONArray addressArray;
private ArrayList<Markers> markerOptionsList;
private Markers markerForDb;
private LatLng markerPosition;
private int counter=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);



}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (counter==0){
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext(),null,null,1);
        try{

            for (Markers marker : markerOptionsList) {
                db.addMarker(marker);
            }
        }catch (NullPointerException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            db.close();
        }

    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if (counter==0){
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext(),null,null,1);
        try{

            for (Markers marker : markerOptionsList) {
                db.addMarker(marker);
            }
        }catch (NullPointerException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            db.close();
        }
    }
    super.onPause();
}


@Override
protected void onStop() {
        if (counter==0){
            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext(),null,null,1);
            try{

                for (Markers marker : markerOptionsList) {
                    db.addMarker(marker);
                }
            }catch (NullPointerException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
                db.close();
            }
        }
    super.onStop();
}



@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
    markerOptionsList = new ArrayList<>();
}


@Override
public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {
    markerPosition = latLng;
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(markerPosition));
    getAddress(latLng);
    AsyncSaveToDb async2 = new AsyncSaveToDb();
    async2.execute(latLng);

}

private void getAddress(LatLng latLng) {
    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + latLng.latitude + "," + latLng.longitude + "&key=AIzaSyBWH6gioY47pZjtCy-lz3rmyYNKVBOZnaA");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Async async = new Async();
    async.execute(url);
}

@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    for (Markers markers :markerOptionsList) {
        double lat = markers.get_lat();
        double lng = markers.get_lng();
        LatLng latlng = new LatLng(lat,lng);
        if (latlng.equals(marker.getPosition())){
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),com.example.fixxxer.mapclicker.MarkerInfoPage.class);
            String addressForText = markers.get_address();
            String countryForText = markers.get_country();
            String locationForText = markers.get_lat() + ", " + markers.get_lng();
            intent.putExtra("address", addressForText);
            intent.putExtra("country", countryForText);
            intent.putExtra("location", locationForText);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public class Async extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, JSONArray> {


    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(URL... params) {
        BufferedReader reader;
        InputStream inputStream;
        JSONArray results = null;
        try {

            StringBuilder responseBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) params[0].openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.connect();
            inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null; ) {
                responseBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            httpResponse = new JSONObject(responseBuilder.toString());
            results = httpResponse.getJSONArray("results");
            inputStream.close();
            reader.close();

        } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray resultList) {
        addressArray = resultList;
        JSONArray responseComponents;
        try {
            if (addressArray != null) {
                JSONObject firstResult = addressArray.getJSONObject(0);
                if (firstResult != null) {
                    responseComponents = firstResult.getJSONArray("address_components");
                    if (responseComponents != null) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < responseComponents.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject currentComponent = responseComponents.getJSONObject(i);
                            if (currentComponent.getString("types").contains("country")) {
                                markerCountry = currentComponent.getString("long_name");
                                markerStreetAddress = firstResult.getString("formatted_address");
                                if (markerStreetAddress==null||markerStreetAddress.isEmpty()){
                                    markerStreetAddress="No address available for this location";
                                }else{
                                    String[] split = markerStreetAddress.split(",");
                                    markerStreetAddress="";
                                    for (int j =0;j<split.length-1;j++){
                                        markerStreetAddress+=split[j];
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (markerStreetAddress==null||markerStreetAddress.isEmpty()) {
            markerStreetAddress = "No address available for this location";
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Marker added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
public class AsyncSaveToDb extends AsyncTask<LatLng, Void, Markers>{

    @Override
    protected Markers doInBackground(LatLng... params) {
        markerForDb = new Markers();
        markerForDb.set_address(markerStreetAddress);
        markerForDb.set_country(markerCountry);
        markerForDb.set_lat(params[0].latitude);
        markerForDb.set_lng(params[0].longitude);
        markerForDb.set_image("image");

        return markerForDb;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Markers markers) {
        markers = markerForDb;
        markerOptionsList.add(markerForDb);
        super.onPostExecute(markers);
    }
}
```

DatabaseHelper class:

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "locations.db";
public static final String TABLE_LOCATIONS = "locations";

public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_ADDRESS = "_address";
public static final String COLUMN_COUNTRY = "_country";
public static final String COLUMN_LAT = "_lat";
public static final String COLUMN_LNG = "_lng";
public static final String COLUMN_IMAGE = "_image";


public DatabaseHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query = "CREATE TABLE " +
            TABLE_LOCATIONS + "(" +
            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COLUMN_ADDRESS + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_COUNTRY + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_LAT + " REAL, " +
            COLUMN_LNG + " REAL, " +
            COLUMN_IMAGE + " TEXT " +
            ");";

    db.execSQL(query);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LOCATIONS);
    onCreate(db);
}

public void addMarker(Markers marker) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_ADDRESS, marker.get_address());
    values.put(COLUMN_COUNTRY, marker.get_country());
    values.put(COLUMN_LAT, marker.get_lat());
    values.put(COLUMN_LNG, marker.get_lng());
    values.put(COLUMN_IMAGE, marker.get_image());
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(TABLE_LOCATIONS, null, values);
    db.close();
}

public void deleteMarker(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_LOCATIONS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_ID + "=\"" + id + "\";");
}

public ArrayList<Markers> getExistingMarkers() {
    ArrayList<Markers> list = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_LOCATIONS;
    Cursor curs = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    curs.moveToFirst();
    while (!curs.isAfterLast()) {

        Markers marker = new Markers(
                curs.getString(1),
                curs.getString(2),
                Double.parseDouble(curs.getString(3)),
                Double.parseDouble(curs.getString(4)),
                curs.getString(5));
        list.add(marker);
    }
    curs.close();
    return list;
}

public Markers getOneMarker(double lat, double lng) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_LOCATIONS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_LAT + "=?" + " AND " + COLUMN_LNG + "=?";
    Cursor curs = db.rawQuery(query, new String[]{String.valueOf(lat), String.valueOf(lng)});
    if (curs != null)
        curs.moveToFirst();

    Markers marker = null;
    if (curs != null) {
        try{
            marker = new Markers(curs.getString(1), curs.getString(2), Double.parseDouble(curs.getString(3)), Double.parseDouble(curs.getString(4)), curs.getString(5));
        }catch (CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    if (curs != null) {
        curs.close();
    }
    return marker;
}
public Markers getfirstMarker() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Markers marker=null;
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_LOCATIONS + " LIMIT 1";
    Cursor curs = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    if (curs != null) {
        curs.moveToFirst();
        try {
            marker = new Markers(curs.getString(1), curs.getString(2), Double.parseDouble(curs.getString(3)), Double.parseDouble(curs.getString(4)), curs.getString(5));
        } catch (CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    return marker;
}
```

DB entity is standard:

```
private int _id;
private String _address;
private String _country;
private double _lat;
private double _lng;
private String _image;

public Markers(int _id, String _address, String _country, double _lat, double _lng, String _image) {
    this._id = _id;
    this._address = _address;
    this._country = _country;
    this._lat = _lat;
    this._lng = _lng;
    this._image = _image;
}

public Markers(String _address, String _country, double _lat, double _lng, String _image) {
    this._address = _address;
    this._country = _country;
    this._lat = _lat;
    this._lng = _lng;
    this._image = _image;
}

public Markers() {

}

public int get_id() {
    return _id;
}

public void set_id(int _id) {
    this._id = _id;
}

public String get_address() {
    return _address;
}

public void set_address(String _address) {
    this._address = _address;
}

public String get_country() {
    return _country;
}

public void set_country(String _country) {
    this._country = _country;
}

public double get_lat() {
    return _lat;
}

public void set_lat(double _lat) {
    this._lat = _lat;
}

public double get_lng() {
    return _lng;
}

public void set_lng(double _lng) {
    this._lng = _lng;
}

public String get_image() {
    return _image;
}

public void set_image(String _image) {
    this._image = _image;
}
```

And finally MarkersInfoPage:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_marker_info_page);
    TextView addressText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.addressView);
    TextView countryText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.countryView);
    TextView position = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latlngText);
    String address = getIntent().getStringExtra("address");
    String country =getIntent().getStringExtra("country");
    String location =getIntent().getStringExtra("location");
    addressText.setText(address);
    countryText.setText(country);
    position.setText(location);
    Button backButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backButton);
    backButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    super.finish();
}
```

I am stuck here for a long time. Any help is priceless.

Comment: what does db.insert(TABLE_LOCATIONS, null, values) returns in "db" class?

Comment: well nothing...its void

Comment: nothing? the method is not void!
public long insert (String table, String nullColumnHack, ContentValues values)
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.content.ContentValues)
As you can see insert returns a long, which is the row id of the inserted row. If is -1, no rows are inserted

Comment: Insertion is working. I get row result.

Comment: Ok, so the problem is not that the database is empty, but that you dont get results from the db on open... Did you try to debug it?

Comment: No. I am very bad with Android Studio and i know only how to do it in eclipse :) . When i populate the list in OnCreate i get a white screen with no map. Maybe i dont use it right. Is it 100% sure that when i use DB it is full after relaunch?

Comment: Yes, if you write and close the database, it is written. Unless you clear it or clear the app data, it stays there

Comment: So, should i use List to fill and if yes, in what method? Bundle savedInstance doesn't do the trick for this right?

Comment: you should get the items from the database when the map is ready (you have the callback), then from these items you fill the map by adding markers. But this has nothing to do with android studio, it's just coding ;)